# Does VHDL permit logic operation in port map

Tags: vhdl

Does VHDL and here I am talking about the latest standard, permit one to carry out logic or arithmetic operation in port map e.g

```
U0: DUT port map (reset => (reset or clear), in1 => (a xor b), in2 => (p+1), out1=> q)
```

Note: in2 is unsigned or integer type port. Rest are standard logic ports.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What VHDL permits, and what tools actually support, are two different things, especially in port maps. For portability, I recommend using intermediate signals regardless of what the standard says.

Comment: As @BrianDrummond says, try to write 'middle of the road' VHDL that all tools will accept. In this case, if you use an intermediate signal it will always synthesise and you've made your life a bit simpler. It's just not worth the saved typing you get from the other way.

Comment: New to 2008. See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.6.3 Port clauses paragraph 6 "If the actual part of a given association element for a formal port of a block is the reserved word **inertial** followed by an expression, or is an expression that is not globally static, then the given association element is equivalent to association of the port with an anonymous signal implicitly declared in the declarative region that immediately encloses the block. ..." The parentheses are redundant. Not likely widely supported for synthesis (if at all).